# Mongo Spark connector write issues

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

We're observing significant increase in duration for writes, which eventually results in timeouts.
We're using replica set based MongoDB cluster.

It only happens during the high peak days of the week due to high volume.
We've tried deploying additional nodes, but it hasn't helped.

Attaching the screen shots.
We're using Mongo-connector 2.2.1 on databricks Apache Spark 2.2.1

Any recommendations to optimise write speed will be truly appreciated. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

how many workers are there? please check DAG, executor metrics for the job. if all writes happening from a single executor, try repartitioning the dataset based on no. of executors.

```
MongoSpark.save(dataset.repartition(50), writeConf);
```